# Recommended free codecs to play DVD in Windows Media Player 11?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, windows-media-player, codec

None of the MPEG-2 codecs recommended on the [WMP help page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/plugins.aspx#DVDDecoder) are available free.
[Without installing a codec pack](http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Why_Codec_Packs_Are_Bad), or (at this stage) installing another media player, are there any recommended free MPEG-2 codecs out there that will give me DVD playback in WMP 11?

**Claification:**
I'm looking for just the specific codecs that will do the job rather than an all encompassing codec pack which may have [unforseen detrimental effects](http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Why_Codec_Packs_Are_Bad).

Comment: My answer has been deleted since it did not answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross the [**GPL MPEG-1/2 DirectShow Decoder Filter**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gplmpgdec/) which gives DVD playback in WMP.

The only possible problem was a warning from the [Windows XP Video Decoder Checkup Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DE1491AC-0AB6-4990-943D-627E6ADE9FCB&displaylang=en) that it does not support synchronization - not a problem for me.

Comment: You should consider marking your answer as accepted if it actually solved your problem.

Comment: @alex: Just leaving it for a while in case anyone knows of anything better.

Comment: That's a good idea. I wanted to suggest that as well.

Comment: I installed this codec, but I still do not have sound with DVD's in windows media player.

Answer (score 4):

Most MPEG-2 codecs are hard to find by themselves, as nowadays most people just download codec packs and don't bother with individual codecs. You can download such a codec pack and then extract the ones that interest you.

The latest K-Lite pack contains two MPEG-2 codecs:

- MPEG-2 (Cyberlink) [version 8.4.0.205]
- MPEG-2 (Gabest) [version 1.0.0.4]

If you want a very complete codec pack, use the [K-Lite **Mega** Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_Mega_codec_pack.htm). 
It is the K-Lite variant with the most codecs. However, as far as MPEG-2 codecs are concerned, only these two codecs are included in all K-Lite versions.

To find a codec's filename, you can use [InstalledCodec](http://nirsoft.net/utils/installed_codec.html) :

> InstalledCodec is a small utility
>   displays the list of all Codec drivers
>   and DirectShow filters currently
>   installed on your system. For each
>   component the following information is
>   displayed: Display Name, Type,
>   Disabled Status, Installed/Modified
>   Time, Description, Company Name,
>   Filename, and more...

Installing a codec is normally only a matter of copying it to its place (normally system32) and issuing regsvr32 on it. See this guide:
[How to install/uninstall DLL and AX codec/filter files](http://www.codecsdownload.com/guides/How_to_install_uninstall_DLL_and_AX_files.htm)

Comment: He just said in a comment he doesn't want a codec pack.

Comment: He edited that AFTER I gave my answer. So I edited my answer as well.

Comment: "Without installing a codec pack" was in the original question :¬)

Comment: Installed and uninstalled, just to get the codecs. Also, the installation is fully parametrized, so one can just install the minimum.