# Where can I find a DVD Decoder Codec for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, windows-media-player, codec

By default the Windows XP Windows Media Player does not support DVDs. It links to their site which suggests different vendors where you have to pay for DVD codecs/decoders. I have found some free ones on the internet but they only give me issues.

[This older superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/52790/recommended-free-codecs-to-play-dvd-in-windows-media-player-11) was helpful but the accepted answer only gave me video playback without any audio playback.

Comment: Warning: If you live in a country that respects U.S. patent law, watching a DVD without paying a royalty for the codec is against the law. IANAL but I would highly recommend that you take the safe route and just buy a professional codec. You're less likely to run into problems like "audio won't play" that way, anyway.

Comment: Also see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software?cb=1

Comment: @allquixotic Thanks for the heads up. I'll be careful how I word this type of question if it ever comes up again.

Comment: @allquixotic: Please also see this discussion: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: It's not about breaking DRM; it's about violating patent law. They are not the same thing. It is conceivable that breaking DRM *could* infringe on a patent, but the question of whether we're "breaking DRM" or not is immaterial if we can already identify a more clear-cut violation of the law; namely, patents. That meta question doesn't say "it's okay to give users links to software that, upon use, would immediately criminalize the user in the majority of the industrialized world".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be quite hard to work out which codec you have used (or not) and just sending you lots of links may not be preferable. So as a work around you can use this free player: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

**EDIT**
As per warsong suggestion, you could try http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/

As per your request, this [Google Search page](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&btnI=I%27m%20Feeling%20Lucky&q=free%20codec%20xp%20dvd) of XP codecs is the best I can offer.

Comment: MPC HC is actually far better

Comment: I would prefer to use Windows Media Player as the codec that works will be installed on multiple computers that already have WMP.